# Propagate changes from GIT to Perforce

Tags: git, perforce

We used to have a Perforce project, lets says myProject in //depot/path/myProject. We recently migrated it to GIT (myProject.git) but still some of the folks are using Perforce. So, if a person A modifies a file A.txt in GIT, what would be best way to propagate that changes to perforce in //depot/path/myProject/A.txt?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [Helix GitSwarm](https://www.perforce.com/gitswarm) with a git fronted (based on GitLab), which is basically an integrated Git server which is mapped to a regular Perforce branch/stream.

But otherwise I don't think you can actually have 2 different SCM on the same project in parallel. Very quickly the two project will diverge.

Let's say at some point for a file you are the same state A :

```
 Perforce:
 A 

 Git:
 A
```

Then if both evolve in parallel you will have something like :

```
Perforce:
A --> B --> D --> E

Git:
A --> M --> N --> P
```

Let's say you want to apply the different A-->E to Git, you can "patch" directly the main line, because you would expect something that look like A.

What you could do is branch from the common ancestor:

```
Perforce:
A --> B --> D --> E
Git:
A --> M --> N -->P--> R
\                  /
 -->B --> D --> E
```

Then you must decide if you merge back R to Perforce or not. But this is going to be a nightmare to maintain because you'll have to track manually at which point you synchronized the 2 tools.

The point of a SCM is to have a consolidated history for your project, if you use 2 at once, you can not get a consistent history anymore.

As mah mentioned it is probably easier to put the legacy system in read-only, and help people to transition to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Git Swarm to mirror content from and to Perforce, you will need to also use Git Fusion to achieve this.

If you do not need the UI and Git Management features of Git Swarm, you can use Git Fusion on it's own.

Git Fusion is a bridge that would sit between the Perforce Server and Git user's.

You would create Git Fusion repos, that map to areas of the depot that the Git user's need to work with.

The Git user's would clone, pull, push etc, via Git Fusion.

Changes they make in branches can then be visible to the Perforce User's, and changes the Perforce User's make can be fetched by the Git user's.

The Git Fusion admin guide is here:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/git-fusion/

Hope this helps,
Jen.